# C# polymorphism - How to get the desired output

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand polymorphism.
In the below code, what is the best way to display **all three texts** without making changes to the main method and without adding any new methods?

```
using System;

class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car c = new BMW();
            c.Start();
        }
    }

    public  class Car
    {
        
        public void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a Car");

        }

    }


    public class Luxury : Car
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a Luxury");
        }

    }


    public class BMW : Car
    {
        public void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am a BMW");
        }

    }
```

Comment: One important thing to mention: You are **not** overriding the Start method of the base Car class in your derived classes. You are **hiding** the Car.Start method, which is an entirely different thing than overriding and behaves differently. (The compiler gave you warnings in this respect; ignore compiler warnings at your own peril...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you made a mistake in your inheritance hierarchy.  I'm guessing `BMW` should inherit from `Luxury`, not from `Car`:

```
public class BMW : Luxury
```

Once that's corrected, it sounds like you're looking for `virtual` methods.  In the `Car` class make your method `virtual`:

```
public virtual void Start()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am a Car");
}
```

This allows inheriting types to override that method.  (Currently your inheriting types are *obscuring* or *hiding* that method, which even generates a compiler warning because that's almost always not what was intended.)  For example:

```
public override void Start()
{
    Console.WriteLine("I am a Luxury");
}
```

This override essentially replaces the parent method, *but* it can also *call* the parent method to effectively "combine" the two:

```
public override void Start()
{
    base.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("I am a Luxury");
}
```

If you continue this pattern down the inheritance hierarchy, then invoking the method on the `BMW` type would first invoke it on the `Luxury` type and then print its own message.  And invoking the method on the `Luxury` type would first invoke it on the `Car` type and then print its message.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Can you explain the use of base.Start(). Including this in the methods of both BMW and luxury classes, won't the start method in the main class Car execute twice?

Comment: @TheChosenOne94: When you call `Start()` on an instance of `BMW` it only invokes that over-ridden method, not the base class methods.  (If there is no override then it invokes the first one it finds up the hierarchy.)  By calling `base.Start()` in the override, you're explicitly invoking the parent class' `Start()` method as well.  Otherwise the override would just execute its own code and nothing more.  So you have the option to override a method or not override it, and you have the option to also invoke the parent's method or not invoke it, all encapsulated in the class itself.

Comment: Another point to note when using inheritance is that when a class does not call base (with exception to abstract method that has no implementation) its typically considered a code smell. Composition and interfaces is a good way to keep implementation decoupled.